# How to bring EWS Managed API 2.0 to nuget

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, ews-managed-api

As of now the latest version of the Exchange Web Services Managed API is 2.0. The only package on nuget is http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/ which is 1.2.
What is the proper way to bring the latest managed api to nuget? Do we have to request a package from Microsoft? Is it legal to create a package and push it to nuget?

Comment: Decided to go ahead and put a package up there: https://nuget.org/packages/EWS-Api-2.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are many Microsoft libs on nuget that have been packaged by 3rd parties, I decided to go ahead and put it up there: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EWS-Api-2.0/